# WCF MSMQ Transaction with Oracle Database Insert

Tags: wcf, oracle, transactions, msmq

I want to create a WCF Service using NetMsmqBinding that will insert data into an Oracle Database.  I'm using MS Visual Studio with C# and .NET 4.0, currently using the System.Data.OracleClient, with Oracle 11.

My requirement is that no data be lost, ever, assuming that the client was able to call the service successfully (thereby putting a message into the MSMQ queue).

Therefore, I am trying design the service such that if the insert into Oracle was successful, then the message is taken off the queue.  If not, then the message should not be taken off the queue so it can be retried for a certain period of time.  I am trying to use a transaction (using the TransactionScope class) to make sure that this works in that way.

However, I am running into executing the INSERT statement into Oracle in the TransactionScope, it throws an exception and seems to crash the IIS worker process.  It appears that WCF/.NET Transactions are not supported by Oracle?  I have not been able to find a clear answer anywhere to show whether or not Oracle supports Transactions from within the .NET framework.  Is this possible to do, or am I not on the right track?  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to support distributed transactions from ODP.net to Oracle you must have *Oracle MTS Recovery Service* running on the client machine. This comes in the ODAC installation package.

Comment: I do have the Oracle MTS Recovery Service running.  However from your comment mentioning ODP.net, does that mean that the System.Data.OracleClient will not work with transactions and that ODP.net must be used instead?  I ask before trying because we already use System.Data.OracleClient and switching over *may* be a lengthy task for us.

Comment: Also, I would like to add that I'm only sending a query to a single database from the wcf service, so I'm not sure that would qualify as a distributed transaction?

Comment: I don't have experience using the microsoft OracleClient so unfortunately I can't help you there. However I have had distributed transactions working via ODP using TransactionScope. One of the gotchas for me was installing MTS recovery service. FYI if the transaction is propogated across more than one machine then by definition it is distributed.